# Custom IRQ handler in Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, nasm, bootloader

I'm trying to learn basic operating system development on a **64-bit Intel Atom** processor (**x86_64**). I'm having trouble getting an interrupt handler working -- I think it's not registering correctly in the Interrupt Vector Table.

Here's the code I load into the boot sector in its entirety:

```
; The code in the boot sector of the disk is loaded by the BIOS at 0000:7c00 
mov ax, 0x07c0
mov ds, ax

; Set es register to 0x0000
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax

; Register IRQ 0x69 handler in the Interrupt Vector Table
cli
mov dx, int_prog
mov [es:0x69*4], dx
mov ax, cs
mov [es:0x69*4+2], ax
sti

; Call interrupt handler for IRQ 0x69
nop
int 0x69

; Busy loop to allow time for human to look at screen
hang:
    jmp hang

; Interrupt Handler
int_prog:
    pusha

    ; Print red 'A' to screen
    mov ax, 0xB800
    mov es, ax
    mov [es:0], word 0x441

    popa
    iret

; Pad with zeroes and add signature at end
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0x55AA
```

I'm expecting a red 'A' to appear on the left corner of the screen, but nothing appears. The section that prints the red 'A' to the screen works fine outside the interrupt handler, so that's not the issue.

All I can assume is that the processor never enters the interrupt handler -- yet I explicitly call it with `int 0x69`.

Is there some kind of *x86-specific* setup I'm missing from my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused about your `org`. If you don't say, Nasm will default to `org 0`. This is consistent with the way you load `ds`. But `int_prog` will be evaluated as... some small value, not 0x7C00 + some small value. You put `cs` in the second word of your interrupt table address. Do we know what `cs` is? "Probably" zero. You've got `ds` set to 0x7C0. Try using `ds` instead of `cs` there. Or, do the whole thing as `org 0x7C00` and make both `ds` and `es` zero. `pusha` and `popa` do not preserve segment registers. Since you alter `es` in your ISR, you might want to save and restore it also (although I don't think it's a problem currently).

Okay, Edit: Fixed the spelling of "of". And... Okay, where's your code? At 0x7C00 - that's where your BIOS (or fake BIOS) loaded it. That can be addressed as segment 0 offset 0x7C00, or as segment 0x7C0 offset 0. It's a good bet that you've jumped to 0:0x7C00, but 0x7C0:0 would also work, and there's a rumor that the BIOS in a certain Compaq Presario model did so. We really shouldn't count on it.

So where's your code for your Interrupt Service Routine? At 0:0x7Cxx or at 0x7C0:xx. You want to put one of those segment:offset combinations into your Interrupt Vector Table (we know that's in segment 0 - you get that part exactly right) Professor Jesus Ramos is right in his advice, but he's thinking about later in the process when we've switched to protected mode.

Because you didn't use an `org` directive, Nasm assumes `org 0`, that is it evaluates addresses as just the file offset. If you'd said `org 0x7C00` Nasm would evaluate addresses as file offset plus 0x7C00. That's what `org` does. In your case, Nasm has evaluated the address (offset part of the address) as just "xx"... and that's what you put in your IVT. So in the segment part of your IVT (the second word) you need 0x7C0. 0:xx isn't going to find your code. Since you've put the known value 0x7C0 in `ds`, that works perfectly.

If I haven't answered your question(s), ask again...

Comment: I performed the changes you suggested and now it works, but I'm having trouble following your explanation on why. Here's what it looks like now: `mov ax, int_prog; mov word [es:0x69*4], ax; mov [es:0x69*4+2], ds`. Was my error because everythign was being offset from `cs` register when I should have been using the segment address I loaded in `ds`?

Answer (score 1):

In x86 you need to setup the interrupt descriptor tables in order for interrupts to work. Take a look at https://github.com/jesus-ramos/not-a-good-os/tree/master/kernel, the files `interupt.s` and `desc_tables.c` will shed some information on this. This is a small kernel I wrote for teaching the basics of x86 and operating systems so feel free to grab whatever you need out of it.

Basically you need to setup the IDT (interrupt descriptor table). Before this you must execute a series of instructions to remap the IRQ table (some `outportb` instructions with the right values), populate your IDT with values and finally issue a `lidt` instruction to load your descriptor table into the appropriate place.

In real mode the IDT is located in addresses `0x0000 - 0x03FF` and consists of 4 byte entries (not sure if 8 bytes on 64 bits but that would mean the upper end of the address range would be 2048 rather than 1024). Just write your real mode pointer to the correct entry in the table (which it looks like you're doing). The issue may be that the incorrect value is getting placed because of the use of `dx` vs `edx`

Comment: I was under the impression the interrupt descriptor table is only needed in protected mode. So I need to set up the IDT even in real mode?

Comment: @VilhelmGray In real mode the IDT is in addresses `0x0000 - 0x03FF`. You just have to put a real mode pointer to your handler (not sure if on 64 bit it's 8 bytes wide). No need to call `lidt` if it's in real mode.

Comment: Since I'm on a 64-bit processor, is the line `mov dx, int_prog` probably the source of my issue, because the `int_prog` pointer doesn't fit in the 16-bit `dx` register?

Comment: @VilhelmGray Yeah from what I can remember entries in there are 4 bytes wide so you might to change it to `mov edx, int_prog`

Comment: That seemed like such a promising lead, but I didn't seem to have any effect. I tried `mov edx, int_prog; mov [es:0x69*4], dx;` but it seemed to have no effect. I also tried `mov edx, int_prog; mov [es:0x69*4], edx;` without the mov for `cs`, but it too had no effect. I do still suspect something is going on in this section of code -- perhaps we have the layout of a function pointer backwards, or something to the effect.